# Python odd number diamond

Tags: python, python-2.x, validation, casting, ascii-art

I worked up a quick diamond program that takes only odd numbers while returning an error with even numbers or 0.

The code looks rather ugly to me, especially with the recurring `int()`. I haven't found out how to clean that up with my ENTER to quit.

```
while True:
    number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
    if number == "":
        print "\nQuitting program...\n"
        break
    elif int(number) == 0:
        print "\nCannot print symbols for a zero value, try again.\n"
    elif int(number) % 2 == 0:
        print "\nThat's an even number, try again.\n"
    else:   
        for i in range((int(number))+1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                None
            else:
                print ("*" * i).center(int(number))

        for i in range((int(number))-1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                None
            else: 
                print ("*" * ((int(number)) - (i + 1))).center(int(number))
```

Comment: Why do you make a separate condition for 0? Zero IS even.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You can test for emptiness of `number` by just `if not number`
- After testing for emptiness, you could go straight to an int by adding `number = int(number)`
- Inside the loops, when you test for `i % 2 == 0:`, and then put `None` as the loop body (that should really be `pass`), you could just test for `if i % 2 != 0:`, and replace `None` with the `else` body, and remove the `else`.
- `0` is even, so you can remove that test.
- You can replace `int(number) % 2 == 0` with `not int(number) % 2`.
- Looking at the `for` loops, the `range` could be changed to `range(1, number-1, 2)`, removing the need for an `if` statement.
- You can also invert the last `range`, so the subtracting from `number` and `1` is not needed.
- Python automatically adds newlines, so the `\n`s aren't really needed.

That leaves us with (after removing a few useless brackets):

```
while True:
    number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
    if not number:
        print "Quitting program..."
        break
    number = int(number)
    if not number % 2:
        print "That's an even number, try again."
    else:   
        for i in range(1, number + 1, 2):
            print ("*" * i).center(number)
        for i in range(number - 2, 0, -2):
            print ("*" * i).center(number)
```

If you want to go functional, you can move your user input checking into a function. In this function you could also check if the user inputs a non-number, such as `abc`, by catching the exception or using `str.isdigit`:

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
        if not number:
            return  # return None when the user wants to quit
        if number.isdigit() and int(number) % 2:
            return int(number)  # return the number, as its odd
        print "That's not a valid input (must be an odd integer), try again."
```

With this function, the rest of your program reduces to:

```
for number in iter(get_input, None):
    for i in range(1, number + 1, 2):
        print ("*" * i).center(number)
    for i in range(number - 2, 0, -2):
        print ("*" * i).center(number)

print "Quitting program..."
```

`iter` calls the function and gives its value until the function returns `None` (the sentinel value).

On a stylistic note:

- You should always have spaced around operators, so `range(int(number)+1)` should be `range(int(number) + 1)` (that's [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).
- You may want to add a big fat comment at the start of your program describing what it does.

Also, nice use of `str.center`, it avoided having too many loops!

Answer (score 6):

In Python, `pass` is how you indicate that nothing happens; you shouldn't just put `None` on a line on its own. Alternatively, note that:

```
if x:
    pass
else:
    y()
```

is the same as:

```
if not x:
    y()
```

except that the latter is much neater.

---

You are right that the repeated `int` is bad form. You might find [*Asking the user for input until they give a valid response*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761) useful in helping you refactor to make `number` an `int` as early as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can just assign a converted value after your check. After that, get rid of all dead code, move the conditions around a bit and you'd end up with something like this. I'd say that `continue`-ing earlier to get rid of another level of indentation is worth it as well.

In the documentation for `range` you can see that the longer form has a `step` argument, which you can use in this case to get rid of the additional test by incrementing by `2`.

```
while True:
    number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
    if number == "":
        print "\nQuitting program...\n"
        break

    number = int(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        if number == 0:
            print "\nCannot print symbols for a zero value, try again.\n"
        else:
            print "\nThat's an even number, try again.\n"
        continue

    for i in range(0, number + 1, 2):
        print ("*" * i).center(number)

    for i in range(0, number - 1, 2):
        print ("*" * (number - (i + 1))).center(number)
```

And then factor it into functions (e.g. the drawing part) and it will be much nicer to handle as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly for structure.

I would have the quiting operations outside the while loop, and have the condition on the while loop as the quitting condition. This makes the code more readable and you avoid having to use brake as a flow control.

You can also use the string class's `isdigit()` function to check if the input is a number and then simply convert it once. This avoids having to do many casts and also prevents the user from braking the program with non numerical input.

```
number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
while number != "":
    if number.isdigit():
        number = int(number)
        if number == 0:
            print "\nCannot print symbols for a zero value, try again.\n"
        elif number % 2 == 0:
            print "\nThat's an even number, try again.\n"
        else:   
            # rest of code ...
    else:
        print "\nCannot print symbols for non numerical values, try again.\n"
    number = raw_input("Enter another odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
print "\nQuitting program...\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your program, but I've syntactically translated it into this:

```
def getInput():
    number = raw_input("Enter an odd number or hit ENTER to quit program: ")
    if (not number):
        return -2
    try:
        n = int(number)
    except:
        print "\nPlease input only integer numbers\n"
        return 0
    if not n:
        print "\nCannot print symbols for a zero value, try again.\n"
    elif not n % 2:
        print "\nThat's an even number, try again.\n"
    return n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1
    while n > 0:
        n = getInput()
        if not n % 2:
            continue    
        for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
            print ("*" * i).center(n)
        for i in range(1, n-1, 2):
            print ("*" * (n - (i + 1))).center(n)
    print "\nQuitting program...\n"
```

Splitting the code into functions is nearly always a good idea, basically in the function to get the input you focus on these annoying cases where the input is not what you would expect and return something already under control to the upper function, there you use that value accordingly.